# Apple Imac g5 power PC and Dual Core parts compatibility

Tags: macos, mac, imac

I have recently bought a nice 20in G5 isight (late 2005 with Powermac processor)
It works but I would be stuck on Tiger or Leopard due to update restrictions. 
I saw a dual core (2006) one on ebay with GPU issues that will end shortly. 
Is it worth buying it for swapping parts? what parts would be compatible? is the gpu on the motherboard or separate?

Comment: *2006 not 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Parts from the two are not interchangeable, one is a PPC architecture, the other an Intel architecture.

Ne'er the twain shall meet.

The newer one will still be stuck on a completely out of date, insecure OS too.
I'd start saving up for something that can run a modern OS.